Postgresql connection number increases and keeps high
I noticed the number of connections to my database can grow dramatically fast, and then drop. The problem is sometimes it doesn't drop itself, and I don't understand the overall behaviour.
Trying to solve the problem, I'm trying to close the session in my Python code:
import db # It's the SQLAlchemy object

engine_container = None
def init(app):
    global engine_container
    with app.app_context():
        if engine_container is None:
            engine_container = db.get_engine()
def cleanup_session(session):
    global engine_container
    session.close()
    engine_container.dispose()
    return
def long_function():
    db_session = db.session
    try:
        # Long functioning code
    except:
        # Process exceptions
        pass
    finally:
        if db_session is not None:
                cleanup_session(db_session)


As you can see from the graph above, most of the connections are idle. In pgAdmin, when trying to see what's behind them, they just show this and not very informative.

Is this behaviour normal? Why, sometimes, the number of connection gains the threshold and database is staying unresponsive for some period of time (today it was ~45 minutes!!! what is very bad). Any suggestions?


Why does your code execute a rollback? It's also your code that is opening new database connections, while others are idle. Did you consider using a connection pool, like pgBouncer?

@FrankHeikens re: "Why does your code execute a rollback?" - The user's code may not be explicitly rolling back. When SQLAlchemy reaches the end of a transaction boundary it will often issue a ROLLBACK before returning the connection to SQLA's connection pool.

I think we would need to see how the SQLAlchemy's pool is configured, rather than just how it is used.

Disposing an engine will only close connections that are not in use. If you are disposing the engine while connections are active then you may end up with orphaned connections. Flask-SQLAlchemy should automatically close the session at the end of the request, manual session closing should not be necessary.

@FrankHeikens I would consider use a pool, do you have any examples of how it can be organized? Thanks!

@jjanes I don't explicitly organize a connection pool, but would like to know more on it.

@snakecharmerb For some unknown reason, the connections have not been closed automatically. But - when I moved the database to the next tier, it looked like they started being closed, the number of simultaneously opened connection now doesn't higher than ~80, maybe it's related with the amount of available memory?
